# copying/marking state in vmware vm: alternte ways to snapshot

Tags: vmware

Snapshot is a way usig which VM states can be saved and it can be reverted back to point in time when the snapshot was taken.

Are there any other ways of doing this? For example, create incremental copies of VM files and restore those copies as needed. Copies can contain only incremental data. Are there any such different alternatives to snaphots? One of the other considerations for me is to use only VMware tools/technologies.

Thanks,
Vivek.

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot is one of the best thing you have for maintaining Virtual Machine state.

It locks the current disk and creates a new disk which will have the incremental data stored.
So when you revert to snapshot same state is restored.

[VCB](http://www.vmware.com/products/vi/cb_overview.html) is another way to take backups, it internally uses snapshots for taking backup.

So AFAIK taking snapshots is the only available way to maintain state of a VM.